# Simultaneously serving web pages and an API with Flask on different ports

Tags: flask, flask-restplus

I intend to serve a Flask API (powered by `flask-restplus`) on :5000, as well as a couple of web pages on :80 (which incidentally are Angular based consumers of the aforementioned API). Is this possible? If so, how doth one go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. You can setup a server such as apache2 or nginx to process requests on port 80 and let flask serve pages on 5000.